# The video sometimes result in a still video using ReplayKit

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

I followed the video that showcases *ReplayKit*. The problem is that
the recorded video that I get from using *ReplayKit* sometimes result in a video that is either only the last frame, or the first. The in game sounds also manages to get recorded and microphone too (if I played with Microphone that is)

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion with the sound. After testing it again it shows that it didn't record the sound either. The video just shows 1 frame for the whole duration of the recorded video.

When I first implemented *ReplayKit*, the video would sometime become only black for the whole video, but that haven't come up for my last 100 tries.

Does anyone have a implementation or tutorial/guide to follow on how to correctly implement *ReplayKit*?

The only difference in my implementation compared to the *ReplayKit* video is that I show the *previewViewController* directly, instead of storing the reference to the *previewViewController*.

I've tried to check for any error messages, but I haven't gotten any.

Link to the video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-605/
(Only works in Safari)

Any clues as to why the video becomes like that?

EDIT: After further testing, it seems like it's not only the first or last frame. I just came upon a video that managed only to get SOME frames of the whole gameplay that I recorded. It's like the *ReplayKit* was lagging behind or something like that.

And also, it's an Iphone 5S with IOS 9.0.2

Comment: I have a similar problem, I stop and start recording often so I'm wondering if it could be that. Have you had any luck?

Comment: Well, after trying out the "Demobots" sample, it seems that it's probably the ReplayKit that has some bugs because it has happened to me when I try to record on the Demobots. It's not as frequent, but it can happen.

Comment: did you ever fix this or get an update on apples side?

Comment: We tried to implement ReplayKit again when iOS 10 came out but nope, still the same. And Apple said that they are working on it, but not when it will be fixed so it'll probably take a few more months to work.

Comment: Similar story on iPhone 6s, video is lagging, sometimes frames are lost. Doesn't look like it is a production ready feature, however Apple's developers claimed they had no problems with it.